# How do i prove this function satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equation?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is the first time i'm trying to apply abstract complex analysis to an *explicit* function . So, i need to see what a correct approach looks like.

In the class, professor had shown easy examples and i am now able to check properties of rational functions. However, i think the problem below is completely different from rational functions.

> Define $f(z)=e^{-1/z^4}$ if $z\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$
>
> (1) Show that $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations everywhere
>
> (2) Show that $f$ is holomorphic everywhere except at $z=0$
>
> (3) Show that $f(z)$ is not countinuous at $z=0$

Since $f$ is differentiable everywhere except $z=0$, $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation except at $z=0$. How do i prove that it satisfies the equation at $z=0$ and is not differentiable at $z=0$?

Moreover why this is not continuous at $z=0$? I cannot find a *way* of approaching $0$ yields discontinuity..

Please Help.

Comment: Well, recall that a function may have partial derivatives at a given point yet not be differentiable in that point. With that idea, set $f(z) = f(x+iy)$ and compute $\partial_xf$ and $\partial_yf$ around zero. What happens then if you make $(x,y) \to (0,0)$?

Comment: @busman Since $z$ is in the exponential, $f$ is not divided into $u+iv$ explicitly. How do you evaluate partial derivatives?

Comment: Okay, you can try
$$\log f(z) = \frac{-1}{z^4} = -\frac{(x+iy)^4}{(x^2+y^2)^4}$$
and perform implicit derivation.

Comment: Check that the numerator has a minus, not a plus (it won't let me edit). Also check that the above expression can be re-written as
$$\log f(z) = \left( - \frac{\bar{z}}{\| z \|} \right)^4.$$

Comment: @busman Thank you. Now it is clear that it is not continuous at 0 hence not differentiable at 0. But what about Cauchy Riemann Equation/?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so with the last comment taken into account, a reformulation of the Cauchy-Riemann equation is the following:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = 0.$$
You can prove this in a rather simple fashion with the aid of the [Wirtinger derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives). Now, assume $\| z \|  > 0$ and consider the expressions given in my comments. Then,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} \log f(z) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline {z}}\left(- \frac{1}{z^4} \right) = 0.$$
Thus,
$$\frac{1}{f(z)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}f(z)=0.$$
Since $z \neq 0$ and $\exp(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, we get
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}f(z)=0.$$
Now, making $z \to 0$ in both sides of the equality we get $\lim_{z \to 0}\partial_{\overline{z}}f(z)=0$ and we are done.